# Insert data quarterly into SQL Server table from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am creating a web app in C#, I have a dropdownlist like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="droptaskrpt" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="droptaskrpt_TextChanged" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Weekly</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Quarterly</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Half Yearly</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Yearly</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If a user selects quarterly, the same data should be re-insert into the table with same value after a quarter.

I am not able to understand what I need to do here:

1. I will write the code on pageload
2. how can I validate the quarter?
3. how can I insert the same data into the table?

I need your help

```
<div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 500px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 2px">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfTask" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfParentId" runat="server" />
                        <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkmulti" runat="server" Text="Assign to Group" AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup="grp" />--%>
                        <br />
                        <div runat="server" id="divuserSelect">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div runat="server" id="divmultiSelect" visible="false">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" Text="Select Customers" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PnlCust" runat="server" CssClass="PnlDesign">
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Customer One</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Customer Two</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Customer Three</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PceSelectCustomer" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCustomer"
                                PopupControlID="PnlCust" Position="Bottom">
                            </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Task Title
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="OnUpdate" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtTaskTitle"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTaskTitle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 7px">
                        Start Date
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" Format="dd MMM yyyy"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Start Time
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="OnUpdate" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtStartTime"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartTime" MaskType="Time" AcceptAMPM="true"
                            Mask="99:99" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" />
                        <h4 style="font-size: x-small">Type A or P to switch AM/PM</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 7px">
                        End Date
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" Format="dd MMM yyyy"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        End Time
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ValidationGroup="OnUpdate" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtEndTime"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndTime" MaskType="Time" AcceptAMPM="true"
                            Mask="99:99" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" />
                        <h4 style="font-size: x-small">Type A or P to switch AM/PM</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Description
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ValidationGroup="OnUpdate" runat="server" Text="*" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtDescription"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%-- checklist for week days --%>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h4>Task Repeat</h4>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="droptaskrpt" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control" OnTextChanged="droptaskrpt_TextChanged" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Weekly</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Quarterly</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Half Yearly</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yearly</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkWeek" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Monday</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" Visible="false" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Thursday</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Friday</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Saturday</asp:ListItem>
                                    <%--<asp:ListItem Value="7">Sunday</asp:ListItem>--%>
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fpTask" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-warning" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.$&*#@()+\-:])+(.doc|.docx|.pdf|.jpg|.png|.jpeg|.xls|.xlsx|.txt|.gif)$"
                            ControlToValidate="fpTask" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="selected file is not valid"
                            Display="Dynamic" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        Task Priority
                                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPriority" CssClass="form-control">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Low">Low</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Medium">Medium</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="High">High</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--<div class="row" runat="server" id="divuser">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        User Feedback
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserFeedBack" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsUserClose" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline" Text="Close By User" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>--%>
            <%--<div class="row" runat="server" id="divadmin">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Admin Feedback
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdminFeedback" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 17px">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsAdminClose" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline" Text="Close by Admin" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>--%>
            <%--<div class="row" runat="server" id="divrating">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Rating
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRating" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>--%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <%--<asp:ImageButton ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/refresh.png" />--%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="Update" ValidationGroup="OnUpdate" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView CssClass="Grid" ID="dgvTask" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="dgvTask_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="dgvTask_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTaskId" Text='<%# Eval("TaskAutoId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr.No">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSrNo" Text='<%# Eval("SrNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTask" Text='<%# Eval("TaskName")+": "+Eval("TaskDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign To">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAssignTo" Text='<%# Eval("AssignTo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTaskAssignDate" Text='<%# Eval("AssignDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTaskEndDate" Text='<%# Eval("EndDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CssClass="action" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="paging" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

all the required html objects

Comment: So your `DropDownList` is inside a `ListView` or `GridView` object? Please post the code.

Comment: @Serge updated my question

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "_the same data should be re-insert into the table with same value after a quarter_"